# Is development provisioning profile still needed on test device after install?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Recently I had to renew my membership as iOS developer.

Testers who have installed a test version of my app, via direct build on device or via ad hoc distribution, are getting warnings that the profiles are nearly expired.

I just removed the relevant profiles on my test iPad and the app still seems to work. Therefore my questions:
-  are the profiles (development and/or team provisioning and/or ad hoc) still needed on test device after installation of app?
- if so: how come the app still seems to work on my test iPad?
- if so: what is the best option for my (previous) testers who still use the test version? Offer new build with new, valid profiles or just have them delete the expiring profiles?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have them delete the nearly expiring profiles and download the new ones. Offer them new builds with the new profile. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't clear to me if the profiles are still needed after installation, because just deleting them doesn't seem to effect the installed apps. Or will they stop working after the expiry dates have passed?

Comment: Well the new one's are needed yes.

Comment: After the profiles expire they can't be used to activate the test app anymore, so yes deleting them is necessary and then when the new profiles are provided the testers can continue their work. There will be no need of new app download sort of speak, the same test app that they have should work with the new profile. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete expired profile from iOS device and try to install new version of application with new profile. When you will send your tested new binary with testflight, development profile will automatically install to their device.